# String or binary data would be truncated. Struggling to find issue for a while, tried different things but still unsure

Tags: html, sql-server

I'm having trouble understanding why my SQL query doesn't work. I have tried a few things but I'm a beginner so I'm a little confused as what to do. I keep getting the same error

> String or binary data would be truncated

My code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StudentFINAL2]
(
     [UserName]        INT         NULL,
     [FirstName]       VARCHAR(50) NULL,
     [SurName]         VARCHAR(50) NULL,
     [DateOfBirth]     DATE        NULL,
     [Course]          VARCHAR(10) NULL,
     [TimeofUpdate]    INT         NULL,
     [CurrentLocation] VARCHAR(20) NULL
)

INSERT INTO Student (UserName, FirstName, SurName, DateOfBirth, Course, TimeofUpdate, CurrentLocation)
VALUES (529455, 'Sam', 'Smith', '1997/04/23', 'ComputerScience', '21:32', 'Fenner')
```

Comment: Course accept only 10 characters. ComputerScience has 15 characters. Also TimeOfUpdate is accept only iny. 21:32 is not int.

Comment: `UserName` being an `INT` is rather odd - `name` usually implies **string-based** values.... I'd rather call this `UserId`. Also: the `TimeOfUpdate` most likely needs to be of type `TIME` (if you want *only* the time), or `DATETIME2(n)` (if you want a date&timestamp of the update) - not `INT`....

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student]
(
     [UserName]        STRING      NULL,
     [FirstName]       VARCHAR(50) NULL,
     [SurName]         VARCHAR(50) NULL,
     [DateOfBirth]     DATETIME    NULL,
     [Course]          VARCHAR(20) NULL,
     [TimeofUpdate]    DATETIME    NULL,
     [CurrentLocation] VARCHAR(20) NULL
)

INSERT INTO Student (UserName, FirstName, SurName, DateOfBirth, Course, TimeofUpdate, CurrentLocation)
VALUES (529455, 'Sam', 'Smith', '1997/04/23', 'ComputerScience', '21:32', 'Fenner')
```

Problems with your query -

1. You are trying to insert more than 10 characters in Course [Increase the size to 20]
2. You are using INT for TimeOfUpdate and inserting a string value - Change the type to DATETIME
3. UserName should be a STRING